# Can I use my existing well/pump to run water to detached garage?

Tags: well, detached-structure

We have a detached garage that we want to convert to living space/in law quarters, but there is currently no water and we are on a well.

Would I need a second well for the garage?  Or is it possible to use my existing well and well pump and run lines to the garage?

If yes, which would be more efficient or cost effective?

Thanks!

Comment: Bazillions of folks supply more than one dwelling from a single well. It's a matter of proper design and protection from freezing.

Comment: I have 15 rooms with water  in a separate buildings (ok it is a horse barn) with shower stalls and water in each stall all on 1 well. Not a problem as @isherwood says+